# Chrome Extension Context Menu Item Not visible

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've followed some tutorials, but for some reason I'm not able to see the extension I added when I right-click.

manifest.json file

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "description": "description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "background.service_worker": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
   "icons": {
    "16" : "icon.png"
   }
}
```

eventPage.js file

```
var contextMenuItem = {
    "id": "id",
    "title": "title",
    "contexts": ["selection"]
}
chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"manifest_version": 3,
"background": {
    "service_worker": ""eventPage.js"
}
```

//OTHERWISE

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"]
},
```

Comment: I've got an error saying "The "background.persistent" key cannot be used with manifest_version 3. Use the "background.service_worker" key instead."

Comment: If you want to use manifest V3 you have to rewrite background section as I've written to you earlier